# How To remove bracketing in Random module

Tags: python, linux, visual-studio

Here is my code:

```
import random
name="srp"
age=14
gender="male"
vote="N/A"
def about_user():
    aboutusr1="Your name is",name,".\nYou are",age,"years old.\nYour gender is",gender,".\nFun fact -",vote," :)"
    aboutusr2="You are my master whose name is",name,".\nYour age is",age,"and your gender is",gender,".\nAlso, I know that",vote
    L1=[aboutusr1, aboutusr2]
    c=random.choice(L1)
    print(c)
abs=input("Ask me :")
if "about me" in abs:
    about_user()
```

Output:

> Ask me :about me ('Your name is', 'srp', '.\nYou are', 14, 'years
>   old.\nYour gender is', 'male', '.\nFun fact -', 'N/A', ' :)')

But I do not want the opening and closing parentheses, single quotes. Also, things like `\n` for the new-line are also not printing. 
Please help me!

Comment: use `print(*c)`

Comment: Instead of your construct of tuples (created by the commas) and lists use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your `aboutusr1` and `aboutusr2` as below (using [str.format()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format))

```
aboutusr1= "Your name is {}.\nYou are {} years old.\nYour gender is {}.\nFun fact - {} :)".format(name,age,gender,vote)
aboutusr2= "You are my master whose name is {}.\nYour age is {} and your gender is {}.\nAlso, I know that {}".format(name,age,gender,vote)
```

output

```
You are my master whose name is srp.
Your age is 14 and your gender is male.
Also, I know that N/A
```

Or as explained by @sim in the comments use `print(*c)` in your code (`*` will  [unpack the tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists))

Answer (score 0):

if you use python 3 you can use fStrings:

```
import random
name="srp"
age=14
gender="male"
vote="N/A"
def about_user(name,age,gender,vote):
    aboutusr1=f"Your name is {name},\nYou are {age},years old.\nYour gender is {gender}.\nFun fact - {vote} :)"
    aboutusr2=f"You are my master whose name is {name}.\nYour age is {age}, and your gender is {gender}.\nAlso, I know that {vote}"
    L1=" ".join([aboutusr1, aboutusr2])
    #Don't understand why this line
    #c=random.choice(L1)
    print(L1)


abs=input("Ask me :")
if "about me" in abs:
    about_user(name,age,gender,vote)
```